# Is there a way in python (using turtle) to draw an cylinder?(Reading height, radius and volume from array)

Tags: python, 3d, python-turtle

I was wondering if there was any way to draw a cylinder/tunnel with python **turtle**(with data (radius, volume and height) from an array)?

The list of modules I am allowed to use are as following :
-astropy v1.3.2
-Beautiful Soup v4.6.0
-cryptopgraphy v1.8.1
-flask v1.1.1
-lxml v4.1.1
-numpy v1.12.1
-matplotlib v3.0.3
-pandas v0.19.1
-PeakUtils v1.1.0
-pillow: Python imaging library (PIL) v4.1.0
-psycopg2 v2.7.1
-PySAL v1.13.0
-requests v2.18.4
-RunStats v1.6.3
-scikit-learn v0.18.1
-scipy v0.19.0
-SortedContainers v1.5.7
-Statsmodels v0.8.0

Can someone please tell me how? (With Code)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try being specific while asking question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as a starting point:

```
from turtle import *

height = 100
radius = 20

color(0.2, 0.5, 0.8)

forward(height)

circle(radius)

setheading(90)
penup()
forward(2*radius)
pendown()
setheading(180)

forward(height)

circle(radius, extent=180)  #  Draw 1/2 of the bottom/circle

done()
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way via turtle using *stamping*:

```
from turtle import *

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

radius, height = [50, 200]  # in pixels

shape('square')
shapesize(radius*2 / CURSOR_SIZE, height / CURSOR_SIZE)
fillcolor('white')
stamp()

shape('circle')
shapesize(stretch_len=radius / CURSOR_SIZE)
backward(height/2)
stamp()

forward(5)
pencolor('white')
stamp()

forward(height - 5)
color('black')
stamp()

done()
```

Lacks true perspective though:

[image]

Comment: When I run it it displays : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 8, in <module>
    shapesize(radius*2 / CURSOR_SIZE, height / CURSOR_SIZE)
  File "/opt/grok/python3/turtle.py", line 2281, in shapesize
    raise NotImplementedError('The `shapesize` function is not currently supported.')
NotImplementedError: The `shapesize` function is not currently supported.

Comment: @EricCao, you're not using the standard Python release but some other *environment*.  You should make such environment specifics clear when you ask your question.

Comment: Here's an snapshot of what I'm running :                                                                                        [link](https://pastebin.com/pHfUNYg7)

Comment: @EricCao, that appears to be your *editing* environment, what do you use to run the code?

Comment: Grok Learning I run it in python terminal

Answer (score 0):

That's what I have to draw a cylinder.

```
  pendown()
  #starts to draw
  turtle.reset()
  #clears the drawing space 
  circle(radius*10)
  forward(length*10)
  circle(radius*10, 180)
  forward(length*10)
  penup()
  right(90)
  forward(100*10)
  #gets the turtle out of the way
  #draws a cylinder
```